# Android- Using SurfaceView is incredibly laggy

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app I have a simple animation where a small bitmap moves across the screen. I have used a surface view to achieve this, but the bitmap moves very laggily, or not at all on some of the emulated devices.From my understanding , this could be because of everything running on the UI thread, but after following an example, I believe I'm using two threads (not 100% sure) I have tried looking into Asynctasks to fix this, but can't seem to figure out how to apply it to what I have.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {


SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Thread ourThread = null;
boolean isRunning = true;

Bitmap background;
Bitmap clouda;


float cloudax;


public MySurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);

}

public MySurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public MySurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    // do stuff that was in your original constructor...
    ourHolder = getHolder();
    ourThread = new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)   context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.island);
    clouda = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.clouda);

    cloudax = screenWidth;

}


public void pause(){
    isRunning = false;
    ourThread.interrupt();
    ourThread = null;
}

public void resume(){
    isRunning = true;

}


public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(isRunning){
        if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;



        Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas(); 


        Rect drawableRect = new Rect(0, 0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());


        canvas.drawBitmap(background, drawableRect, viewRect, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(clouda, cloudax, (getWidth()/2), null);

        if (cloudax > -276) {
            cloudax -= 10;
        }else{
            cloudax = getWidth();
        }

        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

      }

  }




}
```

Comment: You should not alloc heap in a loop, put drawrect and viewRect out of the loop can improve preformance.

Comment: @user3720864 Check the answer I posted to your last question. `drawableRect` and `viewRect` should be class members. Set `drawableRect` when you load the Bitmap, and set `viewRect` in `onSizeChanged()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry, I'm actually still a little bit confused. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/wmBRVJ4p)(I added stars to what I moved/added) what I tried, and it seemed to help a tiny bit, but still stops

Comment: Your changes are correct. If you're running this in an emulator, it probably is going to be slow and choppy. You might be able to turn on hardware acceleration. Other than that, test on a device.

Comment: @MikeM. Worked like a charm thank you. On a side note though, I noticed that when I go to use an editText and it brings up the keyboard, my surfaceview stops being displayed and just turns to white, even on my device(nexus 4). Is this a mistake I made with the graphics, or does it typically do that?